# Oracle EBS can't load applet on firefox

Tags: java, oracle, firefox, runtime

i use IE in common for accessing oracle ebs.. 
but sometimes i'd like to use firefox for doing job in oracle ebs..

what should i do to makes my firefox able to load ebs form (the web-based menu is opened but not with the forms)

Comment: Firefox probably disabled your java plugin as it's not safe to have it enabled (java applets are a great way of deploying trojans/malware on your computer). I suggest you to read about this on the internet, as it's a PC configuration issue, not a development / code issue.

Comment: well thanks @Augusto.. i just migrate my windows to ubuntu then downgrade its jre to version 6.31 and its work..

Answer (score 0):

Firefox ESR version still supports java plugin, for now.

Answer (score 0):

You should start using Oracle's [Java Web Start](https://blogs.oracle.com/ebstech/java-web-start-now-available-for-ebs-121-and-122). This will help you run Oracle Forms in most modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

We start it using Internet Explorer 11 on a windows 7 pc. It requires an old java version and a installed plugin from oracle, but it get started and can open forms

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firefox version 2.0.0.1 in which applet is still working.
Now onward new version of java is not supported to old firefox version so need to apply patches on your server to upgrade Java Web start technology as per given DOC ID 2188898.1